# Store and access a list inside of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I need to merge 2 list into one list based on a field in the two list and then access the information in the merged list.

Example pseudo code

```
List1.merge;
List2.merge2;
MergedList = List1.merge join List2.merge2;
MergedList.Merge2 or MergedList.Any Field in List
```

Comment: Provide some information about lists and your merge purpose, at least a simple sample.

Comment: By merge, do you mean that you want to enumerate two lists in parallel and select a single new element that combines the properties of the two list element types?  If so, there is a [Zip extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) that may get you there.

Comment: Currently I have two list coming in.  Each list with fields and data inside. I need to merge the two list based on one field.  Once merged in a single list I then need to be able to access the fields and data in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What about `Concat`?

```
var myList = list1
    .Where(l => list2
        .Any(l2 => l2.Field == l.Field)
    .Concat(list2
        .Where(l2 => list
            .Any(l => l.Field == l2.Field))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What library do I need to use Concat?  I cannot get it to show up in the auto complete menu when I key in the dot.

Comment: Just add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file and you should be fine :)

Comment: i have that in my console application and still no luck

Comment: Hmm, are you using .NET 3.5 or higher? Right click on your console app project in Visual Studio, click on Properties, then change the "Target Framework" to 3.5 or higher :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example that you should be able to adjust for you needs:

```
using System.Linq; // Add these two lines to the using statements 
                   // at the top of your file
using System.Collections.Generic;

var l1 = new List<Uri>() { new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"), new Uri("http://www.yahoo.com"), new Uri("http://www.google.com") };
var l2 = new List<Uri>() { new Uri("http://www.google.com"), new Uri("http://www.nytimes.com"), new Uri("http://www.facebook.com") };

var q = from Uri uri1 in l1 
        join Uri uri2 in l2 on uri1.Host equals uri2.Host select uri2;

var commonUris = q.ToList();  // Result
```

The critical line is the one around `equals`

Be aware that this might not produce the expected result if any item occurs more than once in any one of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple lambda join?

```
list1.Join(list2, l1 => l1.Field, l2 => l2.field, (l1,l2) => new SomeORAnonymousObjectType { ListItem1 = l1, ListItemType2 = l2 }).ToArray().ToList().ToEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is now solved.  I created a list that referenced a class, that stored my information, and once I did this I was able to manage and access everything I needed.